# Kotlin Unresolved reference: btn_start but i define it in my layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, reference

Here is my code in activity_main.xml

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textColor="#757575"
            android:textSize="18sp">


        </Button>
```

But when i code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    btn_start
```

it will give me error to unresolved reference (btn_start)

Comment: I think you want to do something like this: ```Button btn_start = findViewById(R.id.btn_start)```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/Button

Comment: it didn't work again i looked at the page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin
> synthetics for view binding is no longer supported.

Please refer to the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Comment: it helped a lot. Thanks for the tip you are the best!

Comment: Integrate view binding and then you can access the fields by calling `binding.btn_start`

Comment: @VETLance you can accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: I looked at bindin and i done it. Thank you for your answer